# How to design standalone module in reduxjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, redux

Say we have a `CountryPicker` which on mount will send a request to server to load country list then display it, user can pick a country and it will dispatch a `PICK_COUNTRY` action and update UI correspondingly. Also it will display some helpful information when it fails to load country list. The logic of this component is rather complete and standalone.

Many of our pages use this `CountryPicker` and apparently we want to reuse the code.

Based on the situation, we have a `CountryPicker` React component, a `CountryReducer` and `CountryActions`.

The problem is, some of our pages using `CountryPicker` would like to do some thing more (like retrieve new data according to new country) when user picks a different country.

The solution I can think of is add a `handleSelectCountry` props for `CountryPicker`, and call it with new country payload when user picks a country.

This is kind of ugly to me, is there anyway to do it more unanimously? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Store.subscribe` to watch for changes in the state of the component and trigger actions from there.

http://rackt.org/redux/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe